# Cache an array from ajax request

Tags: javascript, caching, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that I wrote that that does http requests to my web server and then my server processes the data that was sent to it.

```
var domain = window.document.domain;
var known_domains = ["www.a.com", "www.b.com", "www.c.com"];
if(known_domains.indexOf(domain) >= 0){
    // Do an ajax POST here
}
```

Is there a way to make it where I can make an http request to my server to get a JSON array that will populate the `known_domains` variable and cache that for 1 week, then after a week it will request again and reset the variable.

I would like to do this so every time I add new domains to the list I don't have to release an update for the extension.

So basically, how do I cache data with Chrome?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Comment: That seems to be something that will work!

Comment: @Andreas perfect! That does the trick!